# what's the reason of this error

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Hi 
I tried to modify my coredata application and tried to run my application

it give the error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Seriese''

any suggestions to solve that

best regards

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205783/core-data-error-cant-merge-models-with-two-different-entities-named-foo

Comment: I tired all the steps but the same error exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/core-data-migration-problems.html in this tutorial the solution lay

Answer (score 1):

Delete your app from the sim and try again.