# Separate CoreData models not appearing in [NSBundle allBundles]

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an iPhone app that is a complete rewrite of the previous version. But when users get the new version, there are Core Data issues because some of the Entities have similar names. I don't want to use the old datamodel at all.

I looked at SO posts about not merging the datamodels, and instead using *initWithContentsOfUrl*. However, all the examples say to first grab *[NSBundle allBundles]* and iterate through this to find my desired DataModel. 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/restkit/6_iu2mLOgTo/mjwz2fSmHG4J

[Core Data: Error, "Can't Merge Models With Two Different Entities Named 'foo' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205783/core-data-error-cant-merge-models-with-two-different-entities-named-foo)

```
// Look for our managed object model in all of the bundles. (From the app
  // it is in the main bundle but not for unit tests.)
  NSString *modelPath = nil;
  for (NSBundle* bundle in [NSBundle allBundles])
  {
    modelPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyDataModelFilename" ofType:@"momd"];
    if (modelPath)
      break;
  }
  NSAssert(modelPath != nil, @"Could not find managed object model.");
  NSManagedObjectModel* mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] 
                               initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath]];

  objectManager.objectStore = 
    [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:_databaseFilename 
                                 usingSeedDatabaseName:nil 
                                    managedObjectModel:mom 
                                              delegate:nil];
```

However, when I do this, there is only one object in *allBundles* and that URL is the URL to entire .app file itself, not specific '.xcdatamodeld' files.

So how do I point to a specific '.xcdatamodeld' file? I've tried hardcoding my own URLPath but the allocated MOM is always nil - indicating it couldn't find the model at that URL.

Answer (score -2):

It will be a very unpleasant experience for your users.
But you can create a persistent store with a different name from the new model.